# from django.db import models returns No module named mywebsite.settings

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have tried so hard to make this work but it is not working. I have read myriads of answers here in SO but it's been futile.

I installed Python 2.7 and Django 1.6.5. I have created a `virtualenv`, **env** where I created my project and app as well. The **Django Server** is running fine after installing `MySQL-python` and running `manage syncdb` that created all the apps in **INSTALLED_APPS** but if I try to `from django.db import models` it says:

**ImportError: Could not import settings 'mywebsite.settings' (Is it on sys.path? Is there an import error in the settings file?): No module named mywebsite.settings**

I created a `Path` in **Environment Variables** in System variables. Variable name is `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` and its value is `mywebsite.settings`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can either run `python manage.py runserver` from the same directory as your settings.py (that is mywebsite), or you should export PYTHONPATH to have mywebsite.settings in the path by `export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:<path_to_mywebsite>` (for a unix system)

For windows take a look at [how to add to pythonpath in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-7)

Comment: `python manage.py runserver` doesn't have any issue. What is the Windows 7 equivalent of `export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:<path_to_mywebsite>`